# Checking paths in Python

Tags: python, path

I have a path like so:

```
S:\Test\Testing\Tested\A\B\C
```

and a list

```
include = ['S:\Test\Testing',
           'S:\Domino\Testing',
           'S:\Money\tmp']
```

How do I check if the path I have starts with any of the paths in this list?

So in this case the first element would match and it would return True.

Comment: Relevant standard library module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: something like `mypath.startswith(beginning+os.sep)` ?

Comment: How do you determine that you want `S:\Test\Testing` from `S:\Test\Testing\Tested\A\B\C`? Do you want to extract the path exactly three levels deep, or the one to the directory named `Testing` however deep, or some other criteria?

Comment: I just want the first 3 elements of the path to see if another path begins with those 3 elements

Comment: I've updated the question to be more clear

Comment: BTW, the `\t` in "'S:\Money\tmp'" is a tab because the `\` is an escape character. Either double the backslashes to escape the escape character ("'S:\\Money\\tmp'"), use a raw string (r"'S:\Money\tmp'") or use forward slashes ("'S:/Money/tmp'"). And yes, forward slashes will work on Windows too.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it without worrying about manual string comparisons:

```py
from pathlib import PurePath

original_parent_path = PurePath(r"S:\Test\Testing\removed\sub\dirs")

# Only take top 3 directories (S:\ counts as one)
parent_path = PurePath(*original_parent_path.parts[:3])

test_path1 = PurePath(r"S:\Test\Testing\subdir")
test_path2 = PurePath(r"S:\Test\notsubdir")

print(test_path1.is_relative_to(parent_path)) # True
print(test_path2.is_relative_to(parent_path)) # False
```

PurePath makes no access to the filesystem so this does not check if the directories actually exist.

Comment: Sorry this solution is great. I updated my question however to check from a list.

Comment: @Eisen just iterate over the list! it may be practical to use a `for:else` style where you `break` on success and raise in `else` .. or just pack it all into a function and `return`

Comment: _"PurePath makes no access to the filesystem so this does not check if the directories actually exist."_ It's worth noting that using PurePath isn't import for not accessing the filesystem. Creating a concrete path with `Path` also wouldn't access the filesystem, and likewise does not check if the directory exists. It's just that concrete paths provide methods for accessing the filesystem, while pure paths don't.

Comment: @Eisen just iterate over the list until you find one that is a parent directory, also be careful to add `r` before strings with backslashes in them if you don't want them to mean an escape sequence.

Comment: Be mindful that this example won't run as expected on a non-Windows system, where `PurePath(r"S:\Test\Testing\removed\sub\dirs")` will be a path with only one part. Using `PureWindowsPath` explicitly would fix this

Comment: too, Windows works fine with standard separators and just chooses to be awkward

Answer (score 1):

Use [.commonpath()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonpath) from the [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) module:

```
import os

p1 = 'S:\Test\Testing\Tested\A\B\C'
p2 = 'S:\Test\Testing\Hello'

common_path = os.path.commonpath([p1, p2])
common_path
```

output:

```
'S:\Test\Testing'
```

```
include = ['S:\Test\Testing',
           'S:\Domino\Testing',
           'S:\Money\tmp']

common_path in include
```

output:

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import PureWindowsPath as Path

start_path = Path(r"S:\Test\Testing\Tested\A\B\C")

three_deep_path = Path(*start_path.parts[:3])
print(three_deep_path)

test_path = Path(r"S:\Test\Testing\Hello")
print(test_path.is_relative_to(base_path))

bad_path = Path(r"S:\Test\NotTesting\Hello")
print(bad_path.is_relative_to(base_path))
```

outputs

```
S:\Test\Testing
True
False
```

Comment: I like this solution!!! I updated my question however